# send data that contains "/" with URL in Android

Tags: android, url, slash, loopj

I am using web-services to insert data to the MySQL database. I have a `String` data that contains a path of an image like `https://i.imgur.com/fmccR.jpg`. And I am using `LoopJ` libarary to perform this task.

```
String pic = "https://i.imgur.com/fmccR.jpg";
client.get("http://0.0.0.0:8080/WebService/rest/insert/data/"+username+'/'+code+'/'+pic+
```

When I run this It gives this error. `404 , Not Found`. Finally I found the error. That is the `Image URL` contains `"/"`. When I delete this `"/"` It worked fine and It insert the data.

> So How can I send the full `Image URL` with `(With "/")` this `URL`.

Comment: Do you want to remove "/" from a string ??

Comment: No I need to send full URL `https://i.imgur.com/fmccR.jpg` with that Service URL. `/` is the problem that this `String` not inserted in to the Database. But I need to know how can I send that full URL of the image to database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode url while sending it to server and like below

```
String pic = URLEncoder.encode("https://i.imgur.com/fmccR.jpg", "utf-8");
```

And then on server you need to decode back in actual form according to language you are using in web service like

In Java

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

In PHP

```
utf8_decode(urldecode(url));
```

and In C#

```
Server.UrlDecode(url)
```

Comment: I can't encode and send because I have other apps that getting data from this Database. So I can't change them to decode and get the `Image`. Is there anything that possible to send this image?

Comment: this is for sending to server you can save exact url after decoding and so other application can fetch exact urls